# UIAlertView Crashes App

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uialertview

I'm trying to make a UIAlertView on my Parse app but for some reason every time I run it, it crashes and I'm taken to ApplicationDelegate where I get a SIGABRT. Here is my alert code, I'm pretty sure I'm not doing anything wrong because it's worked before...  Is it because I'm loading data into a tableview from Parse?

```
func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) ->    Void in


    }))

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Your crash is caused elsewhere.

Comment: It does work if I remove the alert though.

Comment: That implies that the source of the crash is near where you call the `displayAlert` function. -- Also check if `title` or `message` are `nil`.

Comment: I tried to hard set the titles and messages so that they are always a certain message and it still crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your issue is. You could simplify the code as follows (Xcode 7b6) by eliminating the empty closure and shortening the arguments when possible. But I don't think this is your problem. Instead, you should show the code where you call this function.

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```